# get specific lines in a range pattern from a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I am trying different scenarios now, 1 of those is getting the text between the following 2 strings.

---

Code:

```
Type of msg:          -in_full [+]
>date
>alr text
>ID_on_exit
AWXX-Ready to commit (96) msg type: (10)
**
Type of msg:          -in_full [+]
>date
>alr text
>ID_on_exit
AWXX-Ready to commit (98) msg type: (10)
**
Type of msg:          -in_full [+]
>date
>alr text
>ID_on_exit
AWXX-Ready to commit (96) msg type: (10)
```

I need to get all the occurrences having the same start line and end line. Starting with Type of msg ....... and ending with the last line.

The last string must be at the beginning of the line, as well as the 1st string. I said that, because there are cases where that AWXX code appears in the middle of another lines, I am not interested in those.

I tried something like this, but I am not really good with awk

Code:

```
perl -lne '{if(/"Type of msg:          -in_full \[+\]"/){$#A=-1;$f=1;} if(/^AWXX-Ready to commit (98) msg type: (10)/ && ($f)){print join("\n",@A,$_);next}($f)?push(@A,$_):next;}' test6
```

I also tried with sed, but my files are big, and I think that there is some kind of limitation because it doesn't work with those files but with little files.

Is there any limitation in the size of the file that we process with SED for example?, now I am using sed and it works only in little files, but not in my 100MB logs.

I am also using the following:

```
awk '/^Type of msg:          -in_full \[+\]/{s=x}{s=s$0"\n"}/^AWXX-Ready to commit \(98\)/{print s}' test6
```

For some reason, it shows all the file, instead of what I am looking for. HELP!!

Comment: sed does work even with huge files. Please show some examples.

Comment: I used the following also:

sed -n "/^Type of msg:          -in_full \[+\]/,/^AWXX-Ready to commit \(98\)/p" test5

test5 is a little text I just copied from the original file, it works on the test5 file, but on the original file it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have files here with approx. some million lines and sed works. OK, and what happens if you put the same Regex as in sed also in awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -n '/^Type of msg:\s\+-in_full.\[+\]/,/^AWXX-Ready to commit (96) msg type:/p' file
```

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/^Type of msg:[[:space:]]+-in_full.\[\+\]/,/^AWXX-Ready to commit \(96\) msg type:/' file
```

Comment: thanks!, for some reason the second statement is not matching only the lines starting with AWXX, the guy is taking another lines with that word in the middle.

Comment: When I run the command on my file, it shows all the file, not only the part that we are filtering with the regex.

 sed -n '/^Type of msg:\s\+-in_full.\[+\]/,/^AWXX-Ready to commit (96) msg type:/p' test  
Type of msg:          -in_full [+]
 >date >alr text
 >ID_on_exit 
AWXX-Ready to commit (98) msg type: (10)
Type of msg:          -in_full [+] 
>date >alr text 
>ID_on_exit 
AW AWXX-Ready to commit (96) msg type: (10)
Type of msg:          -in_full [+] 
>date >alr text 
>ID_on_exit 
AWXX-Ready to commit (98) msg type: (10)

Comment: Your file format differs from that in your question. Please put your examples at pastebin **or** feel free to edit your question. In the comment box the code is unfortunately not readable.